# Safari: search producing unpredictable results

Tags: safari, search

I've observed something weird with Safari search. The search is unable to find words that are obviously present.

For example, I went to [this page](http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg19/database/). I know that the phrase 'lincRNA' is present on the page, therefore I expect to be able to search for 'RNA' (which works), 'lincRNA' (which works) and 'ncRNA' (which fails).

Does anyone else have the same experience? Are you able to reproduce this?

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just discovered a hidden feature in Safari search that solves my problem. The attached picture shows the solution.

Safari can search both for instances 'containing' the query or those that 'start with' the query. I imagine the default is 'starts with', which is why I raised the above question.

[image: Safari screenshot]

Comment: Oh wow, I've totally overlooked that. I'd recommend marking this as your answer so it's easier for others that look for the same.

Comment: This just made my day!

Answer (score 1):

This is the desired behavior (by Apple). The only case in which Safari searches within a word is if it's parted through capitalization.

An example to explain why this makes sense. If I'd search for something like "or" it would then also find occurrences in words like "door", "therefor", "store", etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Well, I'm surprised that there is no obvious way to override this default behaviour. They should at least trust there will be users who want what they have designed against... Like moi! ;-)

Comment: Maybe there's some extension that allows regex for search but I couldn't find anything with a quick Google